# What shape should we get by plotting the log-log graph of Inverse Participation Ratio of eigenvectors vs Eigenvalues for a random matrix?

Tags: matlab, random, statistics, linear-algebra, finance

The Inverse Participation Ratio (I.P.R.) of a vector u = (u1, .... um) for i =
1, ..., m is defined as follows:

[image]

When plotting the log-log of IPR of the eigenvectors vs the eigenvalues, L, we should get something interesting, perhaps a straight line like:

[image]

But I am getting a haphazard thing:

[image]

This is my code.

```
m=98; n=753;
H=randn(m,n);
W=1/n*(H*(H'));
[U, lambda] = eig(W);

for i=1:size(U,2)
    IPR(i,1)=0;
    for j=1:98
        IPR(i,1)=IPR(i,1)+U(j,i)^4;
    end
    L(i,1)=lambda(i,i);
end

loglog(L,IPR);
```

Could anyone please point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where have you taken the first graph from? Does the source say anything about the properties of the matrix they've (symmetric, etc)?

Comment: From a paper on financial correlation analysis. Actually I'm trying to reproduce their results to understand it properly. No, there's no special property of the matrix they have taken; it's a purely random matrix.

Comment: According to my knowledge of the paper and Random Matrix Theory, the matrix does have certain constraints such as being zero-mean unit variance, symmetric, and Gaussian. Hence, the IPR of eigenvectors of such matrices tend to follow 1/N.

Answer (score 0):

If we simply plot lambda vs. IPR we can better find the pattern, that is, just by replacing your last line with:

```
plot(L, IPR, '.'); xlabel('Lambda'); ylabel('IPR');
```

[image]

yet I don't know why we can't see the same pattern in the loglog plot!